# How to pass page info in UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0), nil) of pdf creation?

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf

Is there any way to pass page value in this method or some other way of doing it?

So that i can differentiate /Recognize the PDF pages.

Comment: By page value you mean page number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of what you are trying to do is wrong - you add pages sequentially and draw the content of each before finishing the page and starting a new one. As such, you could be using a loop (so you already have an index which represents your page) or you can maintain a count of where you have got to.

Comment: If you know the size of the pages you can calculate the 'current' page number with `UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds`. But you should just maintain a count.